# How to have different versions of an android project on the device?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I need to have different versions of my code on my device when I'm developing my android application. I want to have a copy of my latest code once in a week or so. The reason is that sometimes you make changes to the code and make it worse for a while, then after that you polish your code to include the features. So I need to have a copy of latest *correctly* running version of my code on the device.

I tried to change the app name, to see whether the ide deploys a new copy of my code, but it didn't work and the ide seems to be smarter than that and it replaces the app with the new name. I suspect that I need to change the package which is a little bit frustrating/risky. Anyone knows the solution?

Right now, I'm using Intellij to implement my android project but I think this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the package name.

I use ant build script to do this easily. I created an ant task to rename the package name and make a build.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I use svn to keep track of changes and label which ones are the ones that work then add features and use svn merge commands to combine new features with working code. Then if you want to undo something you can just roll back a revision.

Answer (score 0):

The way I achieved that goal is:

```
- configure the original project as library
- create another project specifying a different package name in the manifest
- you also need to declare all the activities, receivers, etc with the full name in the new manifest
```

In that way switching the code of the original project through different branches you can create different apks and have different version of the app installed at the same on your device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the package name, not the app name, it's pretty easy in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If your package name now is 'com.sina.perch', so just rename it to 'com.sina.perch1' or something else whatever in file 'AndroidManifest.xml' , which looks like:

It will be work.